# Mainline Linux kernels make updates impossible?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, software-updates

Using Ubuntu Kernel Update Utility (UKUU) I installed a mainline Linux kernel (4.16.18). I soon discovered that when starting the Update Manager it requires the new kernel to be uninstalled. The same probably happens with custom built kernels. 
Is there any way to keep the kernel and do updates?

Comment: I wonder if the same thing happens with `apt update` command in Terminal, or not? Maybe give us the output, or a screenshot if it only happens in Update Manager.

Comment: Also please edit to specify what version number of Ubuntu you are currently running.